# How to match multiple keywords in a log file that occur on the same line using bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I created an array with keywords to match in a log file and display the matching lines on standard output. If a line contains more than one keyword, I want the output to highlight all the keywords that it found within a line. Currently, it's coloring only one match. If two keywords are on the same line, only one is colored. The output should be displayed on the standard output which it currently does.

Current Sample output. `E:` keyword is not colored but `Unable` is.

E: **Unable** to locate package docker

```
#!/bin/bash

search_keywords=("ERROR" "Err" "E:" "W:" "Couldn't" "cleanly" "error" "unable" "failed" "fatal")

log_file="/home/user/example.log"

    for keyword in "${search_keywords[@]}"
    do
        grep -n --color "$keyword" $log_file
    done
```

Comment: "_I want to match all the keywords of the array_" - this isn't clear to me. Do you mean you want to identify lines that have all the keywords, or lines that have any of the keywords? What do you want to do or output when you get a qualified match?

Comment: If a line contains more than one keyword, I want the output to highlight all the keywords that it found within a line. Currently, it's coloring only one match. If two keywords are on the same line, only one is colored. The output should be displayed on the standard output which it currently does.

Comment: That's much clearer, thank you. Please would you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/711039/100397) to include that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example outlined by @balki:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

search_keywords=( "ERROR" "Err" "E:" "W:" "Couldn't" "cleanly" "error" "unable" "failed" "fatal" )
data="E: Unable to locate package docker"

declare -a flags

for keyword in "${search_keywords[@]}"; do
    flags+=( -e $keyword )
done

grep -i --color=always "${flags[@]}" <<< "$data"
```

Comment: "E: Unable to locate package docker" is just a line from the log file. I want to search the log file and highlight the keywords.

Comment: Yes, it was an example. You can use your filename instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check `-e` or `-f` option in [man grep](https://manpages.org/grep/1)

```
❯ cat > /tmp/logfile <<EOM
E: Unable to locate package docker
EOM

❯ grep -i --color -f - /tmp/logfile <<EOM
ERROR
Err
E:
W:
Couldn't
cleanly
error
unable
failed
fatal
EOM
```

Both `E:` and `Unable` are highlighed

```
E: Unable to locate package docker
```

Using `-e`,

```
❯ grep --color -e 'E:' -e 'unable' -i /tmp/logfile
E: Unable to locate package docker
```

Comment: How would I use this in a loop? Seem likes I have to supply every keyword after `-e` flag.